# Azure Automation get a file from source control

Tags: azure-automation

Given below is how I run a script in VM using azure automation. The script file is taken from the VM itself and run in the same VM. How can I take the script file from git repository instead?

```
    $ScriptToRun = "c:\temp\Denodo_shutdown.ps1"
    Out-File -InputObject $ScriptToRun -FilePath ScriptToRun.ps1
    Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath ScriptToRun.ps1
    Remove-Item -Path ScriptToRun.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://saemundsson.se/?p=726) post explains the way to have an Azure Automation runbook to save the script to the Storage container and then allowing the VM download it and then running the downloaded script on VM by leveraging CustomScriptExtension.

To try accomplishing your requirement what you can do is, in that above referenced Azure Automation runbook, at initial part, add the code to download the script from source control git repository by invoking a web request to the git repo script url.